# ServiceStack.Redis timeout on Azure

Tags: azure, caching, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm moving my ServiceStack API from Linux/Mono (On my own hardware) to the Azure App Service, using SS 4.5.2. My Redis cache is 3.2 running on a Linux VM. I am **NOT** using the Azure Redis service.

I'm seeing this exception being thrown seemingly at random:

***RedisException - Exceeded timeout of 00:00:03***

The exception seems to be thrown from services using the authenticate attribute, as every stack trace includes *"ServiceStack.ServiceExtensions.GetSession"* and *"ServiceStack.AuthenticateAttribute.Execute"*. I'm currently only using Redis for session storage, so this bit is no surprise.

I'm registering my ICacheClient as follows, which has been working on my previous Linux/Mono setup in production for some time:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
    new RedisManagerPool("SomeRedisMachine:6379")); 

container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

I did see the post on the SS forms: https://forums.servicestack.net/t/redis-exception-exceeded-timeout-of-00-00-03/2301 - However this only seems to apply when using the Azure Redis service, which I am not.

Given this info, there are several questions I will have to find an answer to:

- Does moving the Redis VM to a higher tier have any positive impact on
  this? Currently the VM is one of the smallest available. I will try this today. **Update: Increasing VM size doesn't seem to resolve the issue.**
- Is the latency between Redis VM and the App Service too great? I can't imagine this is a problem, given that the are within the same datacenter.
- Is there some subtle difference between Linux/Mono and Azure App Service (Windows, Presumably backed by some sort of modified IIS) which I need to take into account?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

**Update**

As per mythz  suggestion, I did update to SS v4.5.4. The exception is still thrown, however with a slightly different message (Exceeded timeout of 00:00:10) consistent with the mentioned updated timeout.

I decided to target an Azure Redis Service (As opposed to a Linux VM). I so far see no errors related to Redis in either ServiceStack 4.5.2 or 4.5.4. Perhaps whatever hosts Microsoft is using for their own Redis service have a better network connection and/or are closer to the cluster handling app services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redis TimeoutException is a symptom of an unhealthy environment which is preventing the Redis Client from establishing a TCP connection. This could be as a result of your redis-server instance or Network being overloaded or unreliable.

You can increase the Timeout to give the Redis Client more time to make a connection with:

```
RedisConfig.DefaultRetryTimeout = 10 * 1000;
```

Which is also the new default timeout from ServiceStack.Redis v4.5.4+.

Comment: Updated my question with results from further research. I do agree with you that it has something to do with network conditions on or around wherever my Linux VM lives, Azure Redis service works perfect.